# React native flatlist scroll to top on data source change?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist with a dynamic data source. I change the redux state of the `selectedCategory` and use that to key into the data source object with the value being the data array for the flatlist.

When the `data` prop on the flatlist changes, the UI does update but when I try and scroll to the top with `scrollToOffset` when the data source changes it doesn't seem to work.

If I have scrolled down far then switch the data source to a smaller array it remains scrolled at the bottom.

```
    <FlatList
          ref={ref => (this.listRef = ref)}
          style={styles.articleList}
          refreshing={isFetching}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={isFetching}
              onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
            />
          }
          onMomentumScrollEnd={x => this.onScroll(x)}
          data={allNewsData[selectedCategory.id.toLowerCase()]}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.item}
              activeOpacity={0.85}
              title={item.post_title}>
              <NewsArticleItem item={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.ID.toString()}
        />
```

I tried to run on `componentDidUpdate` and the check is correct and runs when I change the data source for the flatlist, but I believe it is happening too fast? If I set a timeout of like 500ms around the `scrollToOffset` it does work but I'm not doing that...

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevProps.selectedCategory.id !== this.props.selectedCategory.id) {
    console.log('data src changed');
    this.listRef.scrollToOffset({animated: true, offset: 0});
   }
 }
```

It almost seems I need some type of callback to know when the data source of the flatlist changes maybe?